# Matching on primary key without explicitly naming the key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is really a general wondering for ad hoc queries.  Quite often we run ad hoc queries in a development and testing environments, simple queries like:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.User
WHERE UserID = 2
```

Is there any build in functionality for using a primary key in a `WHERE` clause without explicitly defining the name of the column.

It seems logically to me that, as you can only have a single primary key on a table and SQL Server has knowledge of this, you could use syntax like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.User
WHERE PK = 3
```

Where `PK` is a generic term provided by SQL Server for the current primary key that exists on the table.

Reasons why this may not exist:

- What about composite keys, this wouldn't work for them
- You wouldn't use it in a production query
- It's only really syntax sugar

Comment: In one word: **NO**. If you want to define a `WHERE` condition, you need to specify the columns you want to check against

Comment: You're right, there's no built in thing to do this. To achieve it you would have to use dynamic SQL, but it's still not a good idea for a performance/maintainability/security reasons.

Comment: You can use `WHERE IDENTITYCOL = 3` if the PK is an identity column.

Comment: You can arbitrarily query against *identity* columns, using `where $identity=3`, but there's no similar functionality for primary keys. Note that although they're frequently encountered together, `IDENTITY` and `PRIMARY KEY` are orthogonal concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no syntax for this.

You can use `WHERE $identity = 3` if the PK is generally an identity column though.

Or you can use `$rowguid` for columns marked as `ROWGUIDCOL`

Comment: `IDENTITYCOL` is [deprecated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) - `$identity` should be used instead.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Ah yes. [I see that here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx)

Comment: @PhilippeGrondier - Which is why my answer contains the word "if".

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173545.aspx), expression of the `WHERE` clause (this is what you're asking about) can be:

> a column name, a constant, a function, a variable, a scalar subquery, or any combination of column names, constants, and functions connected by an operator or operators, or a subquery. The expression can also contain the CASE expression.

So the answer to your question is no, it cannot be an index.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: NO

Long (and unsafe) answer: yes, using dynamic SQL

```
declare @pk nvarchar(255)

select top 1 @pk = COLUMN_NAME
from information_schema.table_constraints tc
join information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
where tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'Primary Key' and  tc.TABLE_NAME = 'User'

execute('select * from [User] where ' + @pk + ' = 1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly build your WHERE clause by refering to the database metamodel:

```
-- get your pk name
declare @myPrimaryKeyName nvarchar(50) 
set @myPrimaryKeyName = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ccu.Constraint_name
    WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'Primary Key' and tc.TABLE_NAME = 'dbo.User')

-- set your pk value
declare @myPrimaryKeyValue int set @myPrimaryKeyValue = 3

-- build your sql query string
declare @sql nvarchar(max) set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.User WHERE ' + @myPrimaryKeyName + '= ' + @myPrimaryKeyValue 

-- execute your query
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

This is just a draft. You could of course insert the code in a stored procedure with the table name and the value as parameters. It could unfortunately become quite complex as you'll have to deal with multiple data types for `@myPrimaryKeyValue`